# Would it be wrong to use "feeling" here instead of "doing"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idiomatic-language

If you know that the person you're asking about is in a coma, would it be wrong to use "feeling" here instead of "doing"?

A: How is Trey? Is he feeling/doing better?"

B: Not really. He's not feeling/doing so good."

Comment: That is a very specialised context.  I hope it's hypothetical.  Remember that the best questions are about real problems that you face rather than about artificial situations.

Answer (score 1):

If they are in a coma, you would use ‘doing’ since they are not feeling anything. When you say someone is ‘feeling bad’, you mean that they feel bad, meaning they must be conscious. IF they are just ‘doing bad’, they are currently in a bad state.

Otherwise, both options would be viable but ‘feeling’ may sound more formal.

Comment: You don't know how another person is feeling unless they are conscious and able to tell you.

Comment: @KateBunting that was my point